# A way to colorize the #regions in VS Code C#

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get as comfortable as possible with this new IDE (coming from Visual Studio Community for Windows).

I used a very specific color theme that allowed me to understand the parts of the code at a glance. With VS Code though, it's more complicated for me as there aren't many options in the:

```
Settings > editor.tokenColorCustomizations.
```

Is there a way to colorize the #region pre-processor directives with a specific color?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems it has a distinct scope name (`keyword.preprocessor.region`), allowing you to target it with the setting, as the `Developer: Show TM Scopes` command shows:

[image]

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "keyword.preprocessor.region.cs",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000"
            }
        },
        {
            "scope": "keyword.preprocessor.endregion.cs",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It seems the scope includes neither the `#` nor the string though:

[image]

Comment: Does this still works on VSCode 1.49.0? I'm not able to make it work.

Comment: Maybe the scope name has changed?

Comment: I used the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`, but wasn't able to find a particular name for `region`.  Here is a [screen capture](https://imgur.com/HunJFUI).

Comment: Oh, well, that's Python, not C#. The scopes vary from language to language.